# Website changes not reflected

Tags: browser-cache, website-deployment, website-hosting

After changing something in my website and uploading to the server, I don't see the changes in my browser upon reload. The website loads from cache. It gets reflected after I refresh the page twice or thrice.

I need help in figuring out what's wrong.

Comment: Solution which is rather than clearing browser cache or cookies will be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for editing.... Learned my mistake...

Answer (score -1):

Did you cleaned your browser cache. Restart it. Clean cookies and reset your browser to fix it, This may a problem local to your own Laptop/computer, people who will be accessing your web must be getting updated content that you pushed.

Comment: Thanks for your response..  Whatever you are saying in right.. But how can I say this to client who are all viewing my website.. Please explain me if my understanding is wrong...

Comment: May be to confirm this you can try to open your updated web from remote computer, This machine must be different from your local machine, This will confirm that changes you pushed are reflected or not.  If still problem exists, let us know, We will suggest accordingly.

Comment: In remote machine too its loading only cache file even after my files get updated... But when i clear cache its hitting server.... But i want to hit server without clear cache whenever my files are updated...

Comment: Can you try clear to push your changes once again, Before uploading do this and report if there is any problem, First clear your FTP cache, your local browser cache, then upload the changes you have done. I think this can fix your problem.